# Print date from date dropdown date picker calender. Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this simple drop down date picker calendar code . It works and is very simple code. I would like to print the selected date to the console. How can I do it? 
I am new to python and still learning.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

from tkcalendar import DateEntry
root = tk.Tk()
cal = DateEntry(root, width=12, year=2019, month=6, day=22,background='darkblue', foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
#d.get()=DateEntry   
print(d)
cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Make use of [virtual events](https://pypi.org/project/tkcalendar/#virtual-events).

Comment: Why do you use both? ```from tkinter import *``` and ```import tkinter as tk``` I recommend using only ```import tkinter as tk```. Also, avoid importing everything from a module. Even though the code works, it's a bad habit.

Comment: Thanks Ishaan for the advice. Will definitely keep this in mind.